# Prove that: $\left|\int\limits_a^b\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\right|\le \frac{2}{a}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that: $$\left|\int\limits_a^b\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\right|\le \frac{2}{a}$$

$0<a<b$

I'm not asking for a complete solution to this, just a hint or a push in the right direction. I've been struggling with this and haven't really made any progress.

Comment: Integration by parts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrating by parts,

$$\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}x\,dx = \frac{\cos a}a-\frac{\cos b}b -\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx.$$
Then apply the triangle inequality (twice) to get
$$\bigg|\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\bigg|\leqslant \frac1a+\frac1b+\int_a^b\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{2}{a},$$
since $\int_a^b\frac 1{x^2}\,dx = \frac1a-\frac 1b$.

Comment: Sorry can you explain why $\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}x\,dx$ is $\frac{\cos a}a-\frac{\cos b}b + \int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$ and not $\frac{\cos a}a-\frac{\cos b}b - \int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$?

Comment: @Alexander51413 Because I made a mistake :) 
It doesn't matter anyway, the sign is redundant since I applied the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{a}^b \dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx  \\
  &= \dfrac{-\cos x}{x}|_{a}^b+ \int_{a}^b\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2}dx  \\
 &= \dfrac{\cos a}{a} - \dfrac{\cos b}{b}+ J  \\
 &\le \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+  \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{x^2}dx  \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{b}  \\
 &= \dfrac{2}{a}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Also: $I \ge -\dfrac{1}{a} - \dfrac{1}{b}- \displaystyle \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{x^2}dx = -\dfrac{2}{a}$. Thus $|I| \le \dfrac{2}{a}$ as claimed.

Comment: Sorry can you explain why $\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}x\,dx$ is $\frac{\cos a}a-\frac{\cos b}b + \int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$ and not $\frac{\cos a}a-\frac{\cos b}b - \int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$?

Comment: Ah, it's because $-(-\cos x) = \cos x$. Most students ran into this bump and they couldn't find out why the sign changes...

Comment: @DeepSea He's right actually, you're taking $u = \frac1x$ and $dv = \sin x\, dx$, so $du = -\frac1{x^2}\,dx$ and $v=-\cos x$ so applying integration by parts you should get $$\int_a^b u\, dv= uv\big|_a^b - \int_a^b v\,du = -\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\Big|_a^b - \int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx.$$

Comment: Yes. The double negative comes from integration by parts and the other from the negative of cosine.

Comment: @DeepSea : It's a triple negative, not a double negative.